# Express.js API function parameter confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In Express' API documentation it states the template for a function, "app.use([path,] function [, function...])"

However, in the `app.js` file that is created after executing the Express generator there is this line of code, "`app.use('/', routes);`" and route is declared at the top as `var routes = require('./routes/index');`

After looking through `index.js` and its corresponding module.exports, I'm struggling to understand how routes is simply a function or how app itself is a function and can be passed into `var server = http.createServer(app);` when its documentation also states that its only optional parameter is a function.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand that folder structure, but am more confused on how the router or app objects are simply functions and can be passed in as valid arguments to the app.use(...) and http.createserver(...). Just looking at the ./routes/index.js and ./app.js files they seem to me like complex objects.

Comment: `function foo() { .... } ; bar(foo);` is a simply example of how one can pass a function (`foo`) to another function (`bar`). There is nothing magical about this. Functions are values like any other.

Comment: Yes, i know that in javascript functions are objects and thus can be passed into other functions as arguments.  I am stumped on how app and router are functions in the first place

Comment: And why is that exactly? `require('./routes/index')` simply returns a function object. Why is that confusing to you (especially given the fact that you know that functions are objects)?

Comment: I mean there is just so much going on in app.js... first we see "var app = express();" so that must be returning a function.  And then its calling methods on the app function numerous times.  To me it just seems like app has to be an instance of an object constructor and thus a more complicated object with multiple functions declared inside as name:value pairs and can't possibly be just a single function.

Comment: You said yourself, functions are just objects. Objects can have arbitrary properties. I can do `function app() {} ; app.use = function() {};` easily.

Answer (score 0):

Also functions are variables or options! It's a pattern in specific programming languages like JS is one. Not all Languages support this, but there are a lot.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function

> In computer science, a programming language is said to have first-class functions if it treats functions as first-class citizens. Specifically, this means the language supports passing functions as arguments to other functions, returning them as the values from other functions, and assigning them to variables or storing them in data structures.

Exactly this is happening.
In order to structure the files and filesystem representation they are exported and at the end you will find something which copes the function(req, res){}

Answer (score 0):

```
var routes = require("./routes/index");

//inject your route middleware

app.use("/",routes);
app.use("/users",users); //prefix users in url eg: /users/getUsers
```

Here your are specifying which route middleware will be used for request with no prefix "/" you are just requiring the router index.js file where you will be defining your custom routes and telling express to use it as middleware for all your request.

So it will try to map every request that comes to the server to the routes defined in this file and execute corresponding request in your routes/index.js file.

Comment: I understand what is happening with the routing, middleware, and file structure.  I just don't understand how the router and app variables can possibly be functions and thus valid arguments for app.use(...) and http.createserver(...).

Comment: can you provide the snippet for which app and router variables ?